# AngularJS Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using Angular Chart to create six charts (bars & lines) on a website with different measures.

So i am trying to get the chart type from the json file and load it into the canvas class, but this is not working:

```
{
    "modules": [{
        "name": "Chart1",
        "color": "color:red;",
        "type": "chart-bar",
        "series": "SeriesA",
        "daten": [["90", "99", "20", "21", "26", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"]],
        "labels": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"],
        "colours": [{
            "fillColor": "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
            "strokeColor": "rgba(207,100,103,1)",
            "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
            "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
            "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)"
        }]
    }]
}

<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
    <div class="bar-chart-box" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules" width="100px"><div style="{{module.color}}">{{module.name}} </div>       
        <canvas class="{{module.type}}" data="module.daten" labels="module.labels" series="module.series"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to solve that ?

btw: without `{{}}` it didn't work aswell

Comment: Have you added chart.js dependency in your module. var app = angular.module("Bar_Chart", ["chart.js"]);

Comment: Yes the module is available - So when I change the canvas class to "class='chart-bar'", then its working fine. But I don't want to repeat the canvas class six times...

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/master/angular-chart.js. The class "chart-bar" is used to decide which type of chart needs to draw. The discussion can be found here. https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/165 So you must have to pass that class in order to understand the angular chart which type of chart it needs to plot.

Comment: thanks for the links - it helped me for the solution (see below)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution - Change the canvas element as follow:

```
"modules": [{
                "name": "Chart1",
                "color": "color:red;",
                "type": "Line",
                "series": "SeriesA",
                "daten": [["90", "99", "20", "21", "26", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"]],
                "labels": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"],
                "colours": [{ 
                    "fillColor": "rgba(224, 108, 112, 1)",
                    "strokeColor": "rgba(207,100,103,1)",
                    "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
                    "pointHighlightFill": "#fff",
                    "pointHighlightStroke": "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)"
                }]

<div style="height:400px;width:400px;">
<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
    <div class="bar-chart-box" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules" width="100px"><div style="{{module.color}}">{{module.name}} </div>       
         <canvas id="base" class="chart chart-base" chart-type="module.type" chart-data="module.daten" chart-labels="module.labels" chart-series="module.series"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```